# Unsure about what data type to use in swift

Tags: swift, struct, enums

I'm trying to write a "Restriction" of some data type, where a Restriction could be a list of Interest(enum), Experience(a range of years) or isVerified(boolean), etc. I have another class that has a property [Restriction]?.

I'm thinking about using enum but I'm not sure what's the correct/better way to construct this enum? Or maybe use struct? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not a `struct`?

Comment: is there any advantage of using struct over enum or class in this case? I'm not particularly familiar with struct. @tadman

Comment: Think of `enum` as a way of saying "one of these things" where `struct` is "all of these things". An `enum` is ideal for things like user roles, or a type that might be flexible. A `class` is a more formalized `struct`.

Comment: What if I have a Person that has a list of Interest and isVerified boolean, name, etc. where each person is identified by a unique id, would it be better to use class over struct in this case? @tadman

Comment: You'd use a `class` if you're looking to formalize the construction of these things, and it sounds like that's what you're intending to do, so yes. Use `struct` for "dumb" data, `class` for those with a rich set of methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear from you question what "Restriction" means to you, but the way to decide is to say out loud what it means, and then use grammar to pick your types.

A struct is an "AND" type. For example:

```
struct Point {
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
}
```

A Point has an x coordinate AND a y coordinate. If a restriction has an interest and an experience level and a verification status, then that's a struct.

An enum is an "OR" type. For example:

```
enum Color {
    case red
    case blue
    case green
}
```

A Color is red OR blue OR green. An enum case may also have associated data. For example:

```
enum Pattern {
    case solid(Color)
    case striped(Color, Color)
}
```

A Pattern is either solid with a single color OR it is striped with two colors. Notice the grammar again that helps us recognize our type: "x with y OR a with b."

Structs, classes, and tuples are all AND types, so you need some more rules to split them up. Tuples are basically anonymous structs, and they are mostly useful in Swift for short-lived, temporary values, like return values. If you find yourself wanting to create a `typealias` for a tuple, you probably wanted a struct instead. I find people overuse tuples (in Swift; they make more sense in other languages).

Structs are value types, while classes are reference types. The best way to understand the difference is that a value type is *only* its value. Any "instance" of the number 4 is identical to any other instance of the number 4. Nothing "owns" the number 4. You don't care where the number 4 came from. That's a value. The same is true for a Point. The Point (1,2) is entirely defined by the number 1 followed by the number 2. There is nothing else you can say about that Point. If your type is entirely defined by its properties, that is a good case for a struct. It should be easy to define equality between two values.

Classes are reference types. Reference types have identity. Two instances may have all the same property values, but be different "objects." When you want to ask "which one is this?" then you mean a class, not a struct. If you want to make sure two variables are "the same object" (rather than just "equal"), then you mean a class. There is a lot of pressure in Swift to use structs, but in practice, classes are extremely common, particularly in iOS development.

Thinking about what your type means, and saying it with clear language, will help you find the right types for your problem. If you're interested in a longer version of this, see [Learning From Our Elders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3Kg3c8vqsc).

---

EDIT: Looking at your edits, I think what you're really building is a predicate. A predicate is just a function that returns yes or no given some value, and that's what I think a Restriction probably is. It looks like you want a collection of restrictions. I assume you want to then AND them all together.

A very nice way to build a predicate is with a closure. For example:

```
struct Element {
    let interests: [String]
    let experience: Int
}

struct Restriction {
    let passes: (Element) -> Bool

    init(hasInterest interest: String) {
        passes = { $0.interests.contains(interest) }
    }

    init(hasAtLeastExperience years: Int) {
        passes = { $0.experience >= years }
    }
}

let element = Element(interests: ["fishing", "sewing"], experience: 5)

let restriction = Restriction(hasAtLeastExperience: 2)
restriction.passes(element)
```

With this you can easily build up groups of restrictions, apply them with AND or OR, etc.

Comment: it's not necessarily AND type, a Restriction could have any of the properties I mentioned above, but a Restriction that contains none of these properties is also permitted. In this case should I go with enum or a struct that has these properties as optionals.

Comment: It depends on how you use it, but it sounds more like you want a collection of Restrictions rather than a single Restriction with many optionals.

Comment: In fact, Restriction may be best implemented as a protocol, and then you would have an `[Restriction]` with various implementations, such as `struct InterestRestriction`, etc. It's not clear yet how you're using this data structure, but that sounds like the most likely best implementation.

Comment: my question wasn't very clear, I've edited my question

Answer (score 2):

Go with the `Struct` in your case because `Structs` are preferable if they are relatively small and copiable because copying is way safer than having multiple reference to the same instance as happens with classes. Your `interest` can be a list of the `enum` type `Interest`.

```
enum Interest {

}

struct Restriction {
    let interest: [Interest]
    let experience: Int
    let isVerified: Bool
}
```